# Pandas filter list of list values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe like as below

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'single_proj_name': [['jsfk'],['fhjk'],['ERRW'],['SJBAK']],
                              'single_item_list': [['ABC_123'],['DEF123'],['FAS324'],['HSJD123']],
                              'single_id':[[1234],[5678],[91011],[121314]],
                              'multi_proj_name':[['AAA','VVVV','SASD'],['QEWWQ','SFA','JKKK','fhjk'],['ERRW','TTTT'],['SJBAK','YYYY']],
                              'multi_item_list':[[['XYZAV','ADS23','ABC_123'],['ABC_123','ADC_123']],['XYZAV','DEF123','ABC_123','SAJKF'],['QWER12','FAS324'],['JFAJKA','HSJD123']],
                              'multi_id':[[[2167,2147,29481],[5432,1234]],[2313,57567,2321,7898],[1123,8775],[5237,43512]]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Pick the value from `single_item_list` for each row

b) search that value in `multi_item_list` column of the same row. Please note that it could be `list of lists` for some of the rows

c) If match found, keep only that matched values in `multi_item_list` and remove all other non-matching values from `multi_item_list`

d) Based on the position of the match item, look for corresponding value in `multi_id` list and keep only that item. Remove all other position items from the list

So, I tried the below but it doesn't work for nested list of lists

```
for a, b, c in zip(sample_df['single_item_list'],sample_df['multi_item_list'],sample_df['multi_id']):
    for i, x in enumerate(b):
        print(x)
        print(a[0])
        if a[0] in x:
            print(x.index(a[0]))
            pos = x.index(a[0])
            print(c[pos-1])
```

I expect my output to be like as below. In real world, I will have more cases like 1st input row (nested lists with multiple levels)

[image]

Comment: Does it a dupe of your previous question?

Comment: @Corralien it's the same but with nested lists, you need to write a small recursive function to find the matching elements ;)

Comment: Yeah, my real data has nested lists and I need to get matching item string and id from all occurrences in the list. Earlier question was just one occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach which works with any number of nested lists:

```
def func(z, X, Y):
    A, B = [], []
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            a, b = func(z, x, y)
            A.append(a), B.append(b)

        if x == z:
            A.append(x), B.append(y)
    return A, B


c = ['single_item_list', 'multi_item_list', 'multi_id']
df[c[1:]] = [func(z, X, Y) for [z], X, Y in df[c].to_numpy()]
```

Result

```
  single_proj_name single_item_list single_id           multi_proj_name         multi_item_list           multi_id
0           [jsfk]        [ABC_123]    [1234]         [AAA, VVVV, SASD]  [[ABC_123], [ABC_123]]  [[29481], [5432]]
1           [fhjk]         [DEF123]    [5678]  [QEWWQ, SFA, JKKK, fhjk]                [DEF123]            [57567]
2           [ERRW]         [FAS324]   [91011]              [ERRW, TTTT]                [FAS324]             [8775]
3          [SJBAK]        [HSJD123]  [121314]             [SJBAK, YYYY]               [HSJD123]            [43512]
```

Comment: Neat approach. Thanks.

Comment: had an error - `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)`

Comment: Is it because I have multiple nested lists in each of the rows for columns like `multi_item_list` and `multi_id` etc ?

Comment: Can you make sure that you always have a list with single value in `signle_item_list`?

Comment: Let's say if there are duplicates in single item list. how can I drop duplicates in 'single_item_list` and use your code above? I found out that there are some duplicates items in list. Ex: one row contains `['ABC_1234',ABC_1234']. But I want to retain only `['ABC_1234']`. How to drop duplicates?

Comment: can you try: `df[c[1:]] = [func(z[0], X, Y) for z, X, Y in df[c].to_numpy()]`

Comment: Yes, it works. thanks. This doesn't drop duplicates but for code purposes considers only the 1st item, which is good for me. So, no issues and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I made use to `isinstance` to check whether it is a nested list or not and came up with something like below which results in expected output.  Am open to suggestions and improvement for experts here

```
for i, (single, multi_item, multi_id) in enumerate(zip(sample_df['single_item_list'],sample_df['multi_item_list'],sample_df['multi_id'])):
    if (any(isinstance(i, list) for i in multi_item)) == False:
        for j, item_list in enumerate(multi_item):
            if single[0] in item_list:
                pos = item_list.index(single[0])
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_item_list'] = [item_list]
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_id'] = [multi_id[j]]
    else:
        print("under nested list")
        for j, item_list in enumerate(zip(multi_item,multi_id)):
            if single[0] in multi_item[j]:
                pos = multi_item[j].index(single[0])
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_item_list'][j] = single[0]
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_id'][j] = multi_id[j][pos]
            else:
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_item_list'][j] = np.nan
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_id'][j] = np.nan
```